# Argument of type 'HTMLElement | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Element'. Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Element'.ts(2345)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-dom

I have index.html

```html
<body>
    <div id="portal"></div>
    <div id="root"></div>
</body>
```

and want to use the component below in separate `portal div` than `root div`,

```js
import React from 'react';

const portalDiv = document.getElementById('portal');

function Portal1(props) {
  return ReactDOM.createPortal(
    <div>
      {props.children}
    <div/>, 
  portalDiv); //here
}

export default Portal1;
```

But I am getting this error, **Argument of type 'HTMLElement | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Element'.
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Element'.ts(2345)** in VScode.

I am using Typescript.

Comment: Hi, you should change the accepted answer?

Comment: @kakabali Accepted answer needn't always be the one with highest score, right? The one I've accepted was the first one to answer and get me out of stuck. so thanks for suggestion.

I've also upvoted all the answers on this, since all are useful.

Comment: Yes the highest one is the most relevant and should be accepted now

Comment: No. Accepted answer is the one which helped you resolve issue first. 5 years later if someone answers newly and gets highest upvote, doesnt mean it helped the Asker at time it was asked. okay? peace.

Answer (score 268, accepted):

Other people have answered that you should add a null-check, but Typescript also has a non-null assertion that you can use when you are *sure* that the value is never null by adding the `!` operator to the end of your statement:

```
const portalDiv = document.getElementById('your-element')!;
```

Comment: Yeah, good one indeed. (for added info, some time, typescript, probably latest, suggest to use `?` at same place instead of `!`. works fine.

Comment: ! back at ya! I don't know if the above if () {} solutions were possible in my case (maybeI just don't know how) as the jsx library (react-modal) expects a callback returning an html element, not the element directly, so I don't know at what point I could have done the check and got TS to recognize it. So glad you shared. I just wanna know if/when I'd be abusing some escape hatch like this. I wanna be a user not an abuser but maybe this is why they created it.

Comment: Well, take a look at [this example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlhAciKiCuAbDMC8MA8AKgDQB8AFAG4CGGaApgFwyEwA+MaYAJvQGZww9bgEpcpGAG8AUDDkwATvShoFYGAEINNOvQDc0gL7TpoSLADmygGq0GAST7JUmDAHkFhABYKQAd1wCEgodBmZWDi5eASFRGHDxKVl5OD4YcgRndCwqO3oRMRl5YsVlVXVQ+g0DYuNiqB9-GCEAgFEFXwVyAHJK+Ahm126RA0MgA). The `!` check on line 7 is required, because typescript is not 'smart' enough to see that you already checked whether the value is not null in another function.

Comment: kind of a noob to this operator, can you link docs page for this?

Comment: @DinoSaadeh https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator

Comment: You should delete ```#``` from your selector.

Comment: Wow I can't believe nobody mentioned this already. Thank you @Hooman, updating the response.

Comment: This is where I have added the '!'. Thanks for who raised this issue. But why TS can't tell this? 
<code> const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')! as HTMLElement ); </code>

Comment: This is one of the few times using the [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#non-null-assertion-operator-postfix-) is correct.

Answer (score 74):

So I dont know if anyone is still having this problem but there's an easier and straightforward solution to this.
simply declare the modal element with **"as"** keyword
`const modalRoot = document.getElementById("modal-root") as HTMLElement;`
This removes the error.
I suggest looking through this great react-typescript cheatsheet. 
**https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react**

Comment: yeah, that might work, but we call that as inline typecasting, i.e., we're just changing type in place. still I feel, if there is null values, that is, if the div doesn't exist, it will still give null. and the typecasting null as HTMLElement might give error. did you try applying changes?

Comment: I did apply it and it seemed to be the only way to fix the error. And the cheatsheet gives more details as to why this method is recommended. Btw, the HTMLElement type is Element|null type so I don't think it'll give an error. I already tested it

Comment: I like this method because anyone coming across the code would clearly see what the type is. If you wanted, you could always combine the `?` & the `as` keyword.

So you could do something like `const modalRoot = document.getElementById("modal-root") as HTMLElement;` & then when you need to access it and its properties do: `modalRoot?.foobar`.

Answer (score 29):

When we select an HTMLElement inside a DOM Tree using `getElementById` it returns the Element within the document that matches the specified selector, if no match is found it basically returns null.

Let's get the portal element:

```js
let portalDiv = document.getElementById("portal");
```

If the portal exists in the DOM tree it will return the `HTMLElemnt` in case of not found it returns `null`.

So the return type of `getElementById` is `HTMLElement | null`, since the 2nd argument of the `ReactDom.createPrortal(children: ReactNode, element: HTMLElement, id: string)` is strictly `HTMLElement` we have to caste our `portalDiv` to `HTMLElement` inorder to get rid of the warning.

Since we are sure that the `portalDiv` do exists we can use this method to deal with the `null` conditions.

```
let portalDiv = getElementById("portal") as HTMLElement;
```

now we can use `portalDiv` without getting any errors:

```
function Portal1(props) {
  return ReactDOM.createPortal(
    <div>
      {props.children}
    <div/>, 
  portalDiv);
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Since `getElementById` possibly returns null. So you just simply check before using like:

```
function Portal1({ children }) {
  return portalDiv ? ReactDOM.createPortal(<>{children}</>, portalDiv) : null;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

`getElementById` can return `null`, but `createPortal` doesn't accept `null`.

If you ***know*** the portal div will exist, make the code explicit about that:

```
const portalDiv = document.getElementById('portal');
if (!portalDiv) {
    throw new Error("The element #portal wasn't found");
}
```

That will allow TypeScript to narrow the type of the constant, removing the `| null` part of the type. It also gives you a nice proactive warning if someone changes things such that the div isn't there when this code runs anymore.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best solution to this is not to make it either ***null*** or ***HTMLDIVElement*** but rather in the ***use-case*** try to let typescript know that the ***DivElement*** might be empty at the moment, but you will take responsibility of it by just using "!" symbol.

Code sample below:

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './modal-portlet.style.scss';

const modalRoot = document.getElementById('modalRoot');

type Props = {
  children: JSX.Element;
};
const ModalPortlet: React.FC<Props> = ({children}): JSX.Element => {
  const divContainer = window.document.createElement('div');
  divContainer.setAttribute('class', 'modal-container');

  useEffect(() => {
    /**********
     * immediately the component mount append @divContainer as the childNode of @modalRoot in the DOM
     **********/
    modalRoot!.appendChild(divContainer);

    return () => {
      modalRoot!.removeChild(divContainer);
    };
  });

  /************
   * return the createPortal api that takes the children(JSX) and inject it into @divContainer which is already a childNode of @modalRoot
   ************/
  return <>{ReactDOM.createPortal(children, divContainer)}</>;
};

export default ModalPortlet;
```

Answer (score 2):

There is simple solution just add as HTMLAudioElemnt at the end of get Element by ID
const element =  document.getElementById(auduiId) as HTMLAudioElement;

Answer (score 2):

If you are switching React.js files from Javascript to Typescript using node.js, this should be the fix code for you in index.ts, line 8:

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!);
```

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing same error so I tried few different ways but the one that worked for me is handling null condition
i.e. `const portalDiv = document.getElementById('portal')!;`

Comment: what does the ! do?

Answer (score 1):

Since the return type of the function is HTMLElement | null you have to declare the variable as those types or use the `as` keyword.

`const portalDiv: HTMLElement|null = document.getElementById('portal');`

Or using the as keyword we can allow the return type to be something other than HTMLElement

`const portalDiv = document.getElementById('portal') as HTMLElement;`

As mentioned in another answer you can turn off this typescript feature by setting the compiler argument, "strictNullChecks" to false.

Answer (score -3):

For a quick fix just add `"strictNullChecks": false` to your tsconfig.json file.

Comment: This will impoverish the developer experience.

Comment: It could affect the entire app