# React Hook Form Error - Type 'UseFormRegister<FormData>' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef<HTMLInputElement> | undefined'

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I am working my way through a React Tutorial Book. At one point, the author showed me how to build a simple Form, which worked fine. Then, he proceeded to upgrade it to a 'React Hook Form'.

Everything work fine as per the instructions, until the very last line, where he says the following.

*"Add a ref property to the input element in the Header component's JSX and set this to the register function from React Hook Form:"*

At this exact moment, I run into the following error.

```
Type 'UseFormRegister<FormData>' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef<HTMLInputElement> | undefined'.
  Type 'UseFormRegister<FormData>' is not assignable to type '(instance: HTMLInputElement | null) => void'.
    Types of parameters 'name' and 'instance' are incompatible.
      Type 'HTMLInputElement | null' is not assignable to type '"search"'.
        Type 'null' is not assignable to type '"search"'.  TS2322

    103 |       <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    104 |         <input
  > 105 |         ref={register}
        |         ^
    106 |           name="search"
    107 |           type="text"
    108 |           placeholder="Search..."
```

The final code is available at this location - https://github.com/PacktPublishing/ASP.NET-Core-5-and-React-Second-Edition/blob/master/chapter-06/finish/frontend/src/Header.tsx

and I have compared my code to be identical, which I put below.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useSearchParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

type FormData = {
  search: string;
};

export const Header = () => {
  const { register } = useForm<FormData>();
  const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();
  const criteria = searchParams.get('criteria') || '';
  const handleSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
        ref={register}
          name="search"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Search..."
          defaultValue={criteria}
        />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I am still learning my way around React and TypeScript. I understand the error is something about a type mismatch. Specifically the 'search' cannot be null. But beyond that I have no clue how to fix this.

I have looked at the following existing questions. They all seem to be discussing this but not with React Hook Form.

[Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLInputElement' ReactJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48488701/type-null-is-not-assignable-to-type-htmlinputelement-reactjs)

[Argument of type 'HTMLElement | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Element'. Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Element'.ts(2345)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63520680/argument-of-type-htmlelement-null-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of-type-el)

[useRef TypeScript - not assignable to type LegacyRef<HTMLDivElement>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66963289/useref-typescript-not-assignable-to-type-legacyrefhtmldivelement)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It appears to be a common issue, and has been raised multiple times in the linked github issues section. There is no full code example that is provided, so posting my own solution here, just in case, another book reader is stumped like me.

```
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <input
      {...register("search")} defaultValue={criteria}
      placeholder="type here"
      type="text"
    />
  </form>
```

More details here - https://github.com/PacktPublishing/ASP.NET-Core-5-and-React-Second-Edition/issues/11

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Reading the same book and stuck on the exact same part. This helped a ton!

Comment: Thanks, also reading the same book!

Comment: Thank you a lot! One thing to add for people who are trying to adapt it to their codebase: the string inside of `{...register('someString')}` must be the same text as your input's name attribute e.g `<input name='foo'  {...register('foo')} ... />`. Otherwise, `register` will not connect element to the form.

Comment: Thank you for posting a solution that helps solve the authors problem in newer versions of ReactJS

Comment: no problem brotha.

Answer (score 3):

Because you are not using the same version with the book when installing hook-form. The syntax has changed. There are 2 ways to resolve:

- You can change from `ref={register}` to `{...register}`
- **Remove name attribute** and update it to `{...register('search')}`

Answer (score -1):

Check that the package.json has:

```
"react-hook-form": "^6.12.2"
```

And when building:

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```