# Why won't validation fire for untouched dynamically added input fields in React Hook Form?

Tags: reactjs, forms, validation, react-hook-form

TLDR version: For those of you that are well versed in `react-hook-form`, how do you get dynamically added input fields to fire validation when you submit the form? In my current use case, the dynamically added fields have not been touched, so they won't trigger validation when submitting the form.  Once you touch the input fields, the validations trigger.

Long version: So I have a form in a modal.  This form asks to add new members to a team.  There is a [Add Member] button that dynamically adds REQUIRED [First Name] and [Last Name] input fields to the form.  After you add these untouched fields to the form, when you hit the [Save] button, which submits the form, validation on the two REQUIRED fields do not fire.  Validation fires after they are touched.  How to I get these fields to fire validation without having to touch them?

I have tried to research this use case for over a day now and have not found anything that could help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you add members?
I think it would be convenient to help you if you showed me the code.

When expressed in the form of jsx, it can be operated by attaching a react-hook-form ref.

```
function MyForm() {
  const { handleSubmit, register, errors } = useForm();

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      {members.map((memeber) => (
        <div>
          <input
            type=
            name={`${member.id}-fisrtName`}
            ref={register({ required: true })}
          />
          {errors[`${member.id}-fisrtName`] && <span>This field is required</span>}

          <input
            type="text"
            name={`${member.id}-lastName`}
            ref={register({ required: true })}
          />
          {errors[`${member.id}-lastName`] && <span>This field is required</span>}
        </div>
      )}

      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: Your "ref={register({ required: true })}" line of code actually helped me and lead to a solution I used from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67791756/react-hook-form-error-type-useformregisterformdata-is-not-assignable-to-ty. Thanks much!